# How to edit LaTeX preamble in source pane under LyX?

Tags: lyx, preamble

I want to add some lines in LyX preamble but not finding how to do that. If anyone help that would be much appreciated.

See this is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
```

Now I want to add some lines between last two lines;

```
\usepackage{babel}
**I want to put some lines here**
\begin{document}
```

Kindly help; how can I do that?

PS: when I go Document > Settings... > LaTeX preamble; that put those required lines before `\usepackage{babel}` which I don't want.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to tell LyX to not load `babel`, instead loading it 'manually':

1. Document --> Settings --> Language: For *Language package* select *None*.

   [image]
2. In the LaTeX preamble, also in the document settings, add e.g.

   ```
   \usepackage[british]{babel}
   ```

   followed by whatever you need.

Comment: If i do this, unfortunately document give error while compiling... (Error:babe package doesn't found)

Comment: @faiza `babe` is not the same as `babel`.

Answer (score 1):

LyX is somewhat restrictive in what it allows you to do and where. However, if you want something just before `\begin{document}`, perhaps it's sufficient to contain such content as part of the document hook

```
\AtBeginDocument{<your stuff here>}
```

While this will reside *above* your `\usepackage{babel}` instance, it will be executed after it as forms part of the initiation in the `\document` macro (or `\begin{document}`). Note that this does not allow you to add packages via `\usepackage`, as they can only be called from within the preamble, and the `\AtBeginDocument` hook falls *outside* this scope.

If you really want to insert packages *after* [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) and *before* `\begin{document}`, the following hack does that:

```
\let\oldusepackage\usepackage% Store \usepackage
\renewcommand{\usepackage}[2][]{% Update \usepackage
  \oldusepackage[#1]{#2}% Regular \usepackage
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{babel}=0\relax% If babel is loaded, also do the following:
    \oldusepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,showframe]{geometry}
    \oldusepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{##1}}
  \fi
}
```

When you view the Document > LaTeX Log, you'll see [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) loaded *after* `babel`.

Comment: its not making required changes in the document if it resides before \usepackage{babe1}

Comment: I want to put these lines before:  \usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

Comment: @faiza: Is that all? Why don't you include that as part of the regular LaTeX preamble? That is, why do you have include this *after* `\usepackage{babel}`?

Comment: Because it is not making desired changes if i put it somewhere else...

Comment: @faiza: It's true that you can't put `\usepackage{<package>}` inside `\AtBeginDocument`, as `\usepackage` can only be used *inside* the preamble (and the `\AtBeginDocument` hook is executed *outside* the preamble). When I include your code as part of the regular LaTeX preamble I get the desired output, even *with* `babel`. So what are you doing differently?

Comment: Actually i want to put that after \usepackage{babe1}    latekpreamble is putting this before \usepacage{babe1} so it doesn't fix my problem which i see in my pdf version. as my tables gets too wide to fit in a page. i want to shrink them by using this code!

Comment: @faiza: The code you provided that you want to put *after* `\usepackage{babel}` makes no difference where you place it. That's what I'm trying to say. I've added an option for loading your specific content *within* the preamble *after* `babel` and *before* `\begin{document}`. The output I get makes no difference whether I load `geometry` this way or as part of the regular preamble.

Comment: OK, if LyX insists on putting its own `\usepackage[all]{xy}` then use: `\xyoption{pdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}` instead after 
`\usepackage[all]{xy}`